# Change font in Hugo theme

Tags: css, themes, hugo

New to Hugo and css. Trying to change the fonts of the beautifulhugo theme based on these instruction:

See Chandra's Nov 17 post:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/font-selection-in-theme/8803/8

I have downloaded two fonts and placed them in static/fonts

Added the following to config.toml

```
googlefonts = “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Itim|Limelight”
```

Added this to static/css/custom_style.css

```
body {
font-family: ‘Limelight’, cursive;
}
p {
font-family: ‘Itim’, cursive;
}
```

And added this to layouts/partials/head_custom.html

```
 {{ if .Site.Params.googlefonts }}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.Params.googlefonts }}" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
 {{ end }}
```

yet, no changes are visible. Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

Everything should be available here: https://github.com/ixodid198/blog

Answer (score 1):

In config.toml, add

```
[params]
    custom_css = ["css/custom_style.css"]
```

Not sure if this works on all themes generally, but it works on [the theme I'm using](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-coder/).

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I have downloaded two fonts and placed them in static/fonts

Why would you do that if you are using google fonts?

Anyway, did you try removing `http:` form `googlefonts = “http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Itim|Limelight”`

You probably have something down the line in your code that is overwriting you font settings.

It would be helpfull if you could put your site somewhere online so that we can check what is going on.

Comment: @ixodid yeah, there is no file called `custom_style.css` so of course this doesn't work. Also your fonts aren't being called to the page at all. The code you used does not work at all. 

Do you know how to add custom CSS to the Hugo site?

Comment: Hi, no, I do not.

Comment: @ixodid suggest you read the documentation then :) I never worked with Hugo, so I don't know either. But now at least you know what the problem is.